# Excel Formula not working in Google Sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

Trying to use this Excel Formula:
`=IFERROR(INDEX(FILTER(ALL!$B:$B,ALL!D:D="ATL",""),ROW()-4),"")`

but when copied and pasted into Google Sheets, Sheets automatically changes it to
`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(INDEX(FILTER(ALL!$B:$B,ALL!D:D="ATL",""),ROW()-4),""))`

which doesn't work.

Please help:)

---

Comment: what makes you think it doesn't work? breaking down your `FILTER()` formula, you're trying to filter col B and show any instance where D=ATL & "". what are you expecting "" to do?

Comment: Can you please post an example so that I can see where the formula goes wrong? Thanks!

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of expected output

Comment: Remove the `,""` from the filter.